# How to set the start point of clippath

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I'm about to make a shape using `ClipPath()`. But when I draw it, it seems that it starts from the (0.0) coordinates of its parent. But I want it to start from another point (`size.width * 0.25, size.height`). I want to achieve this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
    import 'dart:core';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class TheHill extends CustomClipper<Path> {
      @override
      Path getClip(Size size) {
        var path = Path();

        path.moveTo(size.width * 0.15, size.height);

        path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.25, size.height * 0.99999,
            size.width * 0.40, size.height * 0.92);

        path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.87,
            size.width * 0.60, size.height * 0.92);

        path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.75, size.height * 0.99999,
            size.width * 0.85, size.height);

        path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
        path.lineTo(0, size.height);

        path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
        path.close();

        return path;
      }

      @override
      bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
    }
```

And this is the output (the red bracket is the extra that IDK where is it coming from): 
[image]

Comment: path.lineTo(0, size.height);  path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0); remove this two line and try.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya filled everywhere except where i wanted to

Comment: what shape do you want?

Comment: the hill shape above except the triangle which I marked.

Comment: I've edited the post. please have another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following way.

```
  ClipPath(
          clipper: TheHill(),
          child: Container(
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Custom Clipper :

```
class TheHill extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(size.width * 0.15, size.height);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.25, size.height * 0.99999,
        size.width * 0.40, size.height * 0.92);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.87,
        size.width * 0.60, size.height * 0.92);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.75, size.height * 0.99999,
        size.width * 0.85, size.height);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time for answering this. But the code has the exact reverse result which I want. I want the filled part to empty and empty parts to fill. something like a hill.

Comment: well Im trying to make some animation later on... when using custom painter I cant do that..

Comment: and also it cant assign to any widget so I can only use it as background

Comment: I dont know how to appreciate you for your time. but can we please stick to the clippath? because thats the point of question. or if any thing is wrong with that I would thank you to explain.

Comment: my answer is on clipPath only. did this work or not ?